# conn.open() oracleException was unhandled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, oracle11g, devart

I'm developing a Windows CE app in C# and trying to connect to an Oracle database. I'm using CoreLab.Oracle reference. This is my code:

```
using CoreLab.Oracle; 

namespace SmartDeviceProject1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = "User ID=name;Password=pass;Host=ip;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;Port=1522;Sid=bleh;Unicode=True";
conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from dc_emp ";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        label1.Text = dr.GetString(0);
        conn.Dispose();

    }
}
}
```

Every time I run the project **conn.Open();** gets error : Network error:: A Socket operation was attempted to an unreachable host. So something is wrong with my connection string but I don't know what.

I might add that when I drag and drop a "oracleConnection" component to my form in design mode and edit the properties, my connection is created.

I have read in some forums I must set the "direct" property to true in my connection string, but when I add it to my connection string it says : Unknown connection string parameter Direct

Can someone please help me?

Comment: you have not mentioned DataSource='Database name' in connection string...

Comment: @rr_only4you When i add Database=DBname i get = Unknown connection string parameter Database.

Comment: conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=dbname;User id=UserName;Password=pwd;"; //Use this format and check

Comment: @rr_only4you nope, still no luck :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working! FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT. Had to install Virtual PC 2007 for the VS Emulators. Then configure the Emulator to use the virtual network card.